# calculating a float square root in python

Tags: python, arrays, csv, math

I have this snippet of python code below where I have trying to calculate winds based on a square root formula:

```
 import numpy as np
  import sys
  import math

  data = np.loadtxt(array.csv, dtype='str',delimiter=',', skiprows=1, usecols=(0,1))

  u = data[:,6].astype(float)
  v = data[:,7].astype(float)
  wind=np.array([])

  for t in range(0,3):
      winds=float(math.sqrt((float(u[t])*float(u[t]))+    (float(v[t])*float(v[t]))))
      wind = np.append(wind,float(winds))
      print "u is ",u[t]," v is ",v[t]," wind is ",float(winds)
```

The csv file as shown below:

```
 0.9999,0.333
 0.9566,0.13
 0.9999,0.053
```

Now for some reason why I try to calculate the value winds in the above code I get only 1.

When I define the arrays u and v in the code itself as the following:

```
u[0]=0.9999
u[1]=0.9566
u[2]=0.9999

v[0]=0.333
v[1]=0.13
v[2]=0.053
```

I get floating values for winds.
  How can I tweak the above code so that I can get a floating value for winds in the above code when deriving u and v from a csv file? The csv files that I will eventually use will have a total of 40 u and v values.

Comment: your code has a SyntaxError (`IndentationError: unexpected indent in line 2`). And instead of adding more "parts" to your question try to find the [mcve] with a special focus on **minimal**. That requires that you find the step that doesn't work as expected (please also include what you expect and what you get instead)!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need all your `float` calls there (`math.sqrt` will always return a float!) and you certainly don't need to do an explicit loop if you're using `NumPy`:

```
import numpy as np

u = np.array([0.9999, 0.9566, 0.9999])
v = np.array([0.333, 0.13, 0.053])

wind = np.hypot(u, v)  # equivalent to "sqrt(u**2 + v**2)"
wind   # array([ 1.05389231,  0.96539296,  1.00130366])
```

But with numpy you have to be careful what dtype your arrays are. If you're using integer arrays then numpy will convert the array to be saved to the dtype of the array. (for example 1.1 -> 1)